# Ajax series data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

How do I receive series data to be used in Highcharts? For example:

```
series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Jobs',
                data: [
                    {name: 'Single job customers', y: jobsSingle, color: colours.lightYellow, },
                    {name: '2 job repeats', y: jobsDouble, color: colours.midYellow},
                    {name: '3+ job customers', y: jobsMore, color: colours.yellow},
                ]
            }]
```

How do I make the data part a function that is an AJAX call?

I have tried:

```
data: function() {
                    return [
                        {name: 'Single job customers', y: jobsSingle, color: colours.lightYellow, },
                        {name: '2 job repeats', y: jobsDouble, color: colours.midYellow},
                        {name: '3+ job customers', y: jobsMore, color: colours.yellow},
                    ]
                    }
```

Just to test if it would parse data returned from a function but this doesn't work.

Comment: See [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) from Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do it:

```
function createSurveyChart() {

    $.ajax({
        url: ROOT + 'Ajax',
        data: {
            call: 'survey->spendingPie'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        success: function(returned) {
            $('#surveyChart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    width: 240,
                },
                exporting: {enabled: false},
                credits: {enabled: false},
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y} <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: false,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>:{point.y}{point.percentage:.1f} %'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Jobs',
                        data: returned
                    }]
            });
        }
    })
}
```